# Binary Tree/Search Tree

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, binary-search-tree

I'm beginning to start data structures and algorithms in Python and I am on Binary trees right now. However I'm really confused on how to implement them. I see some implementations where there are two classes one for Node and one for the tree itself like so:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
    self.right = None
    self.left = None
    self.data = data 

class Tree: 
    def __init__(self):
    self.root = None
    
    def insert()
    def preorder()
    .
    .
    .
```

However I also see implementations where there is no Node class and instead all the code goes inside the Tree class without the following

```
def __init__(self):
    self.root = None
```

Can someone please help me understand why there are two different ways, the pros and cons of each method, the differences between them and which method I should follow to implement a binary tree.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are these two ways.

First of all, in the 1-class approach, that class is really the `Node` class (possibly named differently) of the 2-class approach. True, all the methods are then on the `Node` class, but that could also have been the case in the 2-class approach, where the `Tree` class would defer much of the work by calling methods on the `Node` class. So what the 1-class approach is really missing, is the `Tree` class. The name of the class can obscure this observation, but it is better to see it that way, even when the methods to work with the tree are on the `Node` class.

The difference becomes apparent when you need to represent **an empty tree**. With the 1-class approach you would have to set your main variable to `None`. But that `None` is a different concept than a tree without nodes. Because on an object that represents an empty tree one can still call methods to add nodes again. You cannot call methods on `None`. It also means that the caller needs to be aware when to change its own variable to `None` or to a Node instance, depending on whether the tree happened to be (or become) empty.

With the 2-class system this management is taken out of the hands of the caller, and managed inside the `Tree` instance. The caller will always use the single reference to that instance, independent on whether the tree is empty or not.

## Examples

#### 1. Creating an empty tree

1-class approach:

```py
root = None
```

2-class approach:

```py
tree = Tree()
```

#### 2. Adding a first value to an empty tree

1-class approach

```py
# Cannot use an insert method, as there is no instance yet
root = new Node(1)  # Must get the value for the root
```

2-class approach

```py
tree.insert(1)  # No need to be aware of a changing root
```

As the 1-class approach needs to get the value of the root in this case, you often see that with this approach, the root is *always* captured like that, even when the tree was not empty. In that case the value of the caller's `root` variable will not really change.

#### 3. Deleting the last value from a tree

```py
root = root.delete(1)  # Must get the new value for the root; could be None!
```

2-class approach

```py
tree.delete(1)  # No need to be aware of a changing root
```

Even though the deletion might in general not lead to an empty tree, in the 1-class approach the caller must take that possibility into account and always assign to its own root reference, as it might become `None`.

## Variants for 1-class systems

#### 1. A `None` value

Sometimes you see approaches where an empty tree is represented by a `Node` instance that has a `None`-value, so to indicate this is not really data. Then when the first value is added to the tree, that node's value is *updated* to that value. In this way, the caller does no longer have to manage the root: it will always be a reference to the same `Node` instance, which sometimes can have a `None` value so to indicate the tree is actually empty.

The code for the caller to work with this 1-class variant, would become the same as the 2-class approach.

This is bad practice. In some cases you may want a tree to be able to have a `None`-value as data, and then you cannot make a tree with such a value, as it will be mistaken for a dummy node that represents an empty tree

#### 2. Sentinel node

This is a variant to the above. Here the dummy node is *always* there. The empty tree is represented by a single node instance. When the first value is inserted into the tree, this dummy node's value is never updated, but the insertion happens to its `left` member. So the dummy node never plays a role for holding data, but is just the container that maintains the real root of the tree in its `left` member. This really means that the dummy node is the parallel of what the `Tree` instance is in the 2-class approach. Instead of having a proper `root` member, it has a `left` member for that role, and it has no use for its `right` member.

## How native data structures are implemented

The 2-class approach is more like how native data types work. For instance, take the standard `list` in Python. An empty list is represented by `[]`, not by `None`. There is a clear distinction between `[]` and `None`. Once you have the list reference (like `lst = []`), that reference never changes. You an append and delete, but you never have to *assign* to `lst` itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, this makes it understandable! I had one more question, when iterating through (traversing) a tree why is the syntax: "if self.root is None:" and not if "self.root.data is None:"

Comment: This is code you would see in the 2-class approach. To verify if the tree is empty, you should check that there is **no** node. The `root` member of your instance will then be `None`.